# Toolbar button similar to Back/Forward buttons of firefox - xul

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am developing a Firefox addon. I need to create two buttons which exactly looks and operates like back and forward buttons. But the difference is I need to put my own icon inside them. I am completely blank. Any directions will be really helpful.

[Edit]
I am asking for creating two buttons with the look and feel of back/forward button(Although there are two buttons, it seems like one) in the latest Firefox on windows environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy to add your own Image to toolbar buttons. Read these links you'll have your answer & don't forget to link your images for the buttons in CSS file.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Adding_Toolbars_and_Toolbar_Buttons

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Toolbars

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-image

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/custom_toolbar_button

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Toolbars/Creating_toolbar_buttons

For example:

```
<window id="main-window">
  <toolbox id="navigator-toolbox">
    <toolbar id="xulschoolhello-toolbar" toolbarname="&xulschoolhello.toolbarName.label;"
      accesskey="&xulschoolhello.toolbar.accesskey;"
      customizable="true" mode="icons" context="toolbar-context-menu" 
      defaultset="xulschoolhello-hello-world-button"
      insertbefore="PersonalToolbar" />
  </toolbox>
</window>
```

CSS File:

```
 //LInk you image here//
    toolbarbutton.xulschoolhello-toolbarbutton,
    window:not([active="true"]) toolbarbutton.xulschoolhello-toolbarbutton,
    toolbar[iconsize="small"] toolbarbutton.xulschoolhello-toolbarbutton {
      list-style-image: url("chrome://xulschoolhello-os/skin/toolbar.png");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am asking for creating two buttons with the look and feel of back/forward button(Although there are two buttons, it seems like one) in the latest Firefox on windows environment.

Comment: @Selvaraj M A: You can any number of buttons & it's not a big deal. As I said before you can design your own buttons & link to the CSS file, if not you can use the default buttons of FF/XUL & link those in the CSS file. You can position the buttons in XUL.Please check the answer, I've added some extra links for your reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I achieved what I was looking for with few lines of css.