# Nested tool-bar button in xul

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I am having a toolbar-button with type "menu-button". Can I have two toolbar-buttons inside this one?

Comment: How would that work? Buttons inside a button don't sound like a useful UI element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519484/toolbar-button-similar-to-back-forward-buttons-of-firefox-xul/7521624#comment9176776_7521624

Comment: As Wladimir Palant said, you can't have a button inside a button. You can create buttons inside the box & use layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you would like to have a button inside a menu-button, here you go. But, this is not a pretty good UI.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<window id="main-window">
  <toolbox id="navigator-toolbox">
    <toolbar id="xulschoolhello-toolbar" toolbarname="xulschoolhello.toolbarName.label;"

      customizable="true" mode="icons" context="toolbar-context-menu"
      defaultset="xulschoolhello-hello-world-button"
      insertbefore="PersonalToolbar" />
<hbox>
    <row> <button flex="1" type="menu" label="Menu">
       <menupopup>
         <menuitem label="Option 1" oncommand="setText('menu-text','Option 1');" />
         <menuitem label="Option 2" oncommand="setText('menu-text','Option 2');" />
         <menuitem label="Option 3" oncommand="setText('menu-text','Option 3');" />
         <menuitem label="Option 4" oncommand="setText('menu-text','Option 4');" />
       </menupopup>
     </button> </row>
    <row> <button flex="1" type="menu-button" label="MenuButton" oncommand="alert('Button was pressed!');">
       <menupopup>
         <menuitem label="Option A" oncommand="setText('menu-text','Option A');" />
         <menuitem label="Option B" oncommand="setText('menu-text','Option B');" />
         <menuitem label="Option C" oncommand="setText('menu-text','Option C');" />
         <menuitem label="Option D" oncommand="setText('menu-text','Option D');" />
       </menupopup>
     </button></row>
   </hbox>
   <hbox pack="center">
     <description  id="menu-text" value="Testing" />
   </hbox>
  </toolbox>
</window>

</window>
```